# Preciso BAIXAR vários arquivos e após a conclusão do download EXCLUÍ-LOS, tudo automatizado!

Tags: download, bat

Preciso BAIXAR vários arquivos e após a conclusão do download EXCLUÍ-LOS, tudo automatizado. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso usando comandos .BAT??? Ou alguma outra forma de fazer isso??

Answer (score -3):

Sim, usando os comandos curl e del.

Para baixar os arquivos:

```
curl -O Link1
curl -O Link2
curl -O Link3
del Arquivo1
del Arquivo2
del Arquivo3
```